# formatting/parsing form values in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis

I am working with RGeo (PostGIS) and Ruby on Rails, total newbie to both.  I've got a model that contains a coordinates attribute (latitude & longitude).  I am using a text input field when binding a form that that attribute, but I wanted to format the value into a human readable form.  Currently it is being 'rendered' as the raw DB value, i.e., '0101000020E61000009468C9E3698C5EC065FED13769D64740'.  I'd like to format that as something like '-122.193963, 47.675086' for the user.  Conversely, if the user updates the value, I will need to parse it into a format that PostGIS can understand.

I've been searching and reading what I can find about binding data to forms in RoR, but can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing a hex-encoded representation of [well-known binary (WKB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_binary). There are [many geometry accessors](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Accessors) to get coordinate information in different formats or representations. For example:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) AS WKT, ST_Y(geom) AS latitude, ST_X(geom) AS longitude
FROM (
  SELECT '0101000020E61000009468C9E3698C5EC065FED13769D64740'::geometry AS geom
) AS f;

             wkt              | latitude  |  longitude
------------------------------+-----------+-------------
 POINT(-122.193963 47.675086) | 47.675086 | -122.193963
```

On the Ruby RGeo side, similar information can be obtained using [WKBParser](http://dazuma.github.io/rgeo/rdoc/RGeo/WKRep/WKBParser.html). For example, in [tc_wkb_parser.rb](https://github.com/dazuma/rgeo/blob/master/test/wkrep/tc_wkb_parser.rb) you could do something similar:

```
parser_ = ::RGeo::WKRep::WKBParser.new
obj_ = parser_.parse('0101000020E61000009468C9E3698C5EC065FED13769D64740')
print [obj_.y, obj_.x]  # [-122.193963, 47.675086]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I would prefer to do this 'formatting' in the UI layer rather than the data layer.  I am familiar with the database functions, but am trying to figure out how to format/parse the values within the form binding logic.

Comment: @Mike it looks like you need [RGeo::WKRep::WKBParser](http://dazuma.github.io/rgeo/rdoc/RGeo/WKRep/WKBParser.html); see above

Comment: Thanks Mike. You've been helpful, but I guess my question was too simple being such a newbie. I was struggling with how to get the correctly formatted value in the HTML rendered by RoR. Finally figured out it was as simple as changing 
`<%= f.text_field :location %>`
to
`<%= f.text_field :location, :value => @object.location_coordinates.to_s %>`