# How Can i return Longitude and latitude from a point RGEO Postgis

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgis, postgresql-9.3

I have a table in my database with location city, state, zip, and a point

the point in my database looks like this `0101000020E6100000000000E0087B52C0000000402F6B4440`

When i run this command i get this:

```
1.9.3-p547 :014 > coords = "ST_GeographyFromText('#{Location.first.coords}')"
2014-09-08 11:46:55 DEBUG --   Location Load (77.4ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" LIMIT 1
=> "ST_GeographyFromText('POINT (-85.28800201416016 48.596500396728516)')"
```

what i want to do if figure out how to pull and set each latitude and longitude from that

```
   Latitude = "48.596500396728516"
   Longitude = "-85.28800201416016"
```

I need these so i can use it with Google maps...

Comment: possible duplicate of [formatting/parsing form values in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335430/formatting-parsing-form-values-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ST_Y(geom)` for latitude and  `ST_X(geom)` for longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

unless someone else has an easier solution:

coords = "ST_GeographyFromText('#{Location.first.coords}')"

lat, lng = coords.gsub(/[^-.0-9\s]/, "").strip.split(" ")

if there is a faster way to do this... let me know because i have to do this 100,000 + times